# PrintPreviewDialog no navegador

Tags: c#, vb.net, impressão

Eu tenho o seguinte código num projeto MVC dentro de um cshtml:

```
                var w = window.open('', "print", "height=400,width=600");
                w.document.write(json.html);
                w.document.close();
                w.setTimeout(w.print, 1000);
```

Ele faz tudo o que eu preciso, abre uma aba de impressão, e imprime o que estiver dentro do "json.html"..

Preciso fazer a mesma coisa, mas em VB.Net, e estou tendo muita dificuldade na hora de abrir a aba de impressão, tudo o que consegui até agora foi abrir uma aba em branco da seguinte forma:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Imprimir", "<script>window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600, height=400');</script>")
```

Minha dúvida é: como faço para abrir essa tela de impressão? e como faço para editar o conteúdo que estará escrito na página de impressão?

Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o comando certo seja este, caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida:

Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Imprimir", "window.print();")